# Adruiono unable to return value

Tags: arduino

My goal is to test individual servos for a project I'm doing.
Which may have faulty servos or bad wiring,

though the program I created for testing simply asks and returns an integer from input, then attaches a servo to it. But fails to return the correct value.

Code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo s;
int pin;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Enter Pin");
}

void loop() {
  
  // Getting Input
  while (Serial.available() == 0) {}
  pin = Serial.parseInt();
  
  Serial.println(pin); // returns value given. <-- this is where it breaks and always returns "0".

  //attaching servo
  s.attach(pin);

  // Testing Servo
  s.write(90);
  delay(1000);
  s.write(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine but it reads '\n' (EOL) character and parses it to 0.
Calling parseInt with **SKIP_ALL** and ignore '\n' helps to solve the issue:

```
pin = Serial.parseInt(SKIP_ALL, '\n');
```